# Is that possible to highlight all the pods using ONE service?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

If I want to see all the pods using my service *toto*, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check, all the pods connected to your service, you should do:

```
kubectl get service <svc_name>

[root@ip-10-0-1-162 centos]# kubectl describe service <svc_name>
Name:              <svc_name>
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=config
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                None
Port:              http  9042/TCP
TargetPort:        9042/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.13.117:9042,192.168.13.248:9042,192.168.13.34:9042
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

The Endpoints are the POD IP on which that service is serving

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, but I understand that a pod use a service, so if I have a service, can I know which pod (or pods) are using it?

Comment: Okay, you can describe your service using: `kubectl describe service <svc_name>` and the endpoints in that output is the pod IP's on which that service is connected